# Add custom emoticons to BlackBerry Messenger chatfield

Tags: blackberry

I want to add smileys from my third party application to the bbm chat field. How do I do it programmatically? Jingu-Smiley App has this functionality. I looked through the BlackBerry API documentation, but didn't find any API to add smileys to BBM chat.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots of the smileys from Jingu?  I think they're just exposing smileys that are already part of BBM, rather than adding their own.

Comment: Hi http://www.blackberryrc.com/blackberry-apps/system/2011/1109/5316.html provided the link of jingu app which is third party app using which able to insert smiley..